# How to get the character before the cursor? Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Question's in the title. I'm using a text-widget, and I want to get the character that was last typed.

My current idea is to get the character before the cursor, but I can only get the character after the cursor, this is what I have to do that: `codeBox.get(codeBox.index(tkinter.CURRENT))`

So is there anyway to get the last typed character, or to get the character before the cursor. I only want 1 character, not the whole text widget.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text widget indexex support various modifiers, including the ability to select *N* characters before or after a given index.

To get the character immediately before the cursor you need to back up one character from the "insert" index. To do so, use the "-1 characters" or "-1c" modifiers:

```
codeBox.get("insert-1c")
```